# How to get the XPath of the following phrase where I only have the ID which changes depending upon the user?

Tags: selenium, xpath

To get the XPath where the id changes depending upon the user logged in.

```
<td class="dataCell" id="j_id0:mainForm:j_id36:j_id147:tblProduct:13:j_id148" colspan="1" width="3%">
  <span id="j_id0:mainForm:j_id36:j_id147:tblProduct:13:stsGetRatePlan">
   <span id="j_id0:mainForm:j_id36:j_id147:tblProduct:13:stsGetRatePlan.start" style="display: none">
     <img src="/resource/1307120499000/zqu__ajaxLoading" height="18" width="18">
   </span>
   <span id="j_id0:mainForm:j_id36:j_id147:tblProduct:13:stsGetRatePlan.stop">
     <span id="j_id0:mainForm:j_id36:j_id147:tblProduct:13:panProductSelectComplete" onclick="A4J.AJAX.Submit('j_id0:mainForm',event,{'similarityGroupingId':'j_id0:mainForm:j_id36:j_id147:tblProduct:13:j_id149','parameters':{'j_id0:mainForm:j_id36:j_id147:tblProduct:13:j_id149':'j_id0:mainForm:j_id36:j_id147:tblProduct:13:j_id149','selProduct':'a0f6000000386vMAAQ'} ,'status':'j_id0:mainForm:j_id36:j_id147:tblProduct:13:stsGetRatePlan'} )">
<img id="j_id0:mainForm:j_id36:j_id147:tblProduct:13:imgRadioBtnUnchk" src="/resource/1307120499000/zqu__radioBtnUnChk" height="18" width="18">
   </span>
  </span>
 </span>
</td>
```

Comment: Which xpath you want to find ?

Comment: which phrase  you want to locate?

Comment: I want to get the xpath of the following line which contains a radio button to select a product- <img id="j_id0:mainForm:j_id36:j_id147:tblProduct:13:imgRadioBtnUnchk" src="/resource/1307120499000/zqu__radioBtnUnChk" height="18" width="18">
   </span>

Comment: You need the xpath of radiobutton ??

Comment: Can you share some more outerHTML of the `<td>` tag?

Comment: yes, that's the radio button for to select on of the product. @SiddheshKalgaonkar

Comment: sure @DebanjanB <tr class="dataRow odd" onmouseover="if (window.hiOn){hiOn(this);}" onmouseout="if (window.hiOff){hiOff(this);}" onblur="if (window.hiOff){hiOff(this);}" onfocus="if (window.hiOn){hiOn(this);}">

Comment: Can you get me a bit more of outerHTML till a `id` is found?

Comment: <tr class="dataRow odd" onmouseover="if (window.hiOn){hiOn(this);}" onmouseout="if (window.hiOff){hiOff(this);}" onblur="if (window.hiOff){hiOff(this);}" onfocus="if (window.hiOn){hiOn(this);}"><td class="dataCell" id="j_id0:mainForm:j_id36:j_id147:tblProduct:13:j_id148" colspan="1" width="3%"> the Id changes depending upon the User. So, Is there any way to take the xpath depending upon the Product name? @DebanjanB

Comment: We need to traverse down the HTML with respect to an unique `id` or some unique `linkText` or `ProductName`. So I need some of the `outerHTML`. Please update the `HTML` in the Question area as a text to help me to analyze.

Comment: Please post a link to the page and update the question with what, specifically, you are trying to locate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with the below xpath -

`//img[starts-with(@id,'j_id') and starts-with(@src,'/resource')]`

Let me know whether it works or not.

Comment: but the thing is there is around 20 products listed there with the id increased by 1 per product. The xpath provided by you will select all the products there. That's the problem I am facing.

Comment: Soura needs on the other basis. Not on the basis of ID

Comment: Exactly Siddhesh, Is there any other way to get the xpath by name of the product?

Comment: Is there any search functionality implemented in your page ?? If yes, you can search the product and we can select that particular product easily.

Comment: No, there is no search functionality.

Comment: You can try with indexing.

Answer (score 1):

If it's the only image with "imgRadioBtnUnchk" on the id.

```
//img[contains(@id,'imgRadioBtnUnchk')]
```

Answer (score 0):

If the id or name of an element keeps changing or is dynamic, you will need to find a static label/element on the page or in the DOM that does not change and write a relative XPath based on that.